# Need JRE path for Java 8 in mac

Tags: java, eclipse

I just installed java 8 in my mac. But when I am trying to set latest JRE in elcipse, am not getting what path I should specify.

For JRE 7, it is showing the path 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path for mine is:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Type `java -version` in a console to find out your exact version and replace **1.8.0_20** with the version that you have.